# Alternate InstallShield SetupCompleteSuccess Dialog

Tags: installshield

I was wondering if it's possible to alternate the SetupCompleteSuccess dialog for InstallShield based on certain conditions.  As hyperlinks on dialogs only work with MSI version 5.00 and above, I have the following conditions set on SetupCompleteSuccess and SetupCompleteSuccessWithLink

VersionMsi >= "5.00"

and

VersionMsi < "5.00"

The problem I'm facing is that SetupCompleteSuccess appears to have a special sequence order of -1 so I'm stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Windows Installer doesn't make this trivial with how their hyperlink control works. This interaction in particular is a bad one.

Here's one approach I suspect would work, but haven't had a chance to try out. In sequence -1, instead of putting the name of a Dialog, put the name of a custom action that chooses between your two alternatives, and invokes the selected one with `MsiDoAction` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom action to emit temporary data into the InstallUISequence table to redirect which dialog is -1 based on VersionMSI.

Personally, I'm of the opinion that people don't really read the dialogs in an installer anyways so I rarely ask questions or tell important information.  I'd move the "view website" type requirement to the first run of the application itself.